# Boundedness of RHS implies existance of invariant cube

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, invariance

Consider a system of ODEs of the form $$\dot x_1 = f_1(x_1,x_2)-g_1(x_1,x_2)x_1 \\ \dot x_2 = f_2(x_1,x_2)-g_2(x_1,x_2)x_2,$$where $f,g$ are bounded, Lipschitz-continuous functions. (Then by the existence and uniqueness theorem, solutions exist - even more, by boundedness of $f,g$ they exist on $\mathbb{R}$.)

My question is: Do these assumptions of $f$ and $g$ imply that there exists an closed, invariant cube, $[0,K]\times [0,K]$, for some $K>0$ ? If yes, does this cube contain all attractors of the system ?

Comment: Are there perhaps more conditions, for instance positivity constraints? As it is, one can shift parts between the terms of the differences.

Comment: @LutzL Yes, sorry, there are, I implicitly assumed that $f_k>0$ and $g_k>0$ and forgot to mention it explicitly in my question above. I didn't understood what you meant by your last sentence. Could you details that, please ?

Comment: DOES REALLY NO ONE HAVE AN IDEA ? IT 50 POINTS PEOPLE (WHICH IS TOO MUCH FOR ME TO GET WASTED)

Comment: Your assumption is obviously not true for arbitrarily small negative $g_1$, $g_2$. In fact using standard arguments  you can derive condition for boundedness of $x_1, x_2$ based solely in $g_1,g_2$. Note that for bounded $f_1,f_2$ their values do not influence the boundedness properties of $x_1,x_2$ only the region of attraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming suitable positivity constraints for $f_k$ and $g_k$, the vector field points towards the inside of the first quadrant on the positive half axes.

If the $g_k$ are bounded away from zero, then for a large enough box attached to the coordinate axes the vector field will point inwards also on the other two sides of the box.

Then apply the Poincare-Bendixon theorem.

---

### Details

If $0<f_k<M$ and $n<g_k$ then $f_k(x)-g_(x)x_k<M-nx_k\le0$ for $x_k\ge K=M/n$.

On the other sides one has $f_1(0,x_2)-g_1(0,x_2)·0>0$ and $f_2(x_1,0)-g_2(x_1,0)·0>0$.

Thus $F=(f_1-g_1x_1,f_2-g_2x_2)$ points upwards on the $x_1$-axis, right on the $x_2$-axis, down on $x_2=K$ and left on $x_1=K$.

One needs the positive lower bound for $g$ because otherwise one can construct examples where $g_1(x)=1/(1+x_1)$. Then if $f_1(x)>1$, the difference $f_1-x_1/(1+x_1)$ is always positive, allowing for infinite growth of the solutions.

Comment: Is there an analogue statement concerning the locations of the attractors for higher dimensions ? Because actually I was interested in the case for $n$ equations as in my question but wanted to make it more concrete, so I chose to stick to two equations,falsely  thinking that any answer would generalize to arbitrary dimensions (because Poincare-Bendixson is only valid für $n=2$).

Comment: (What exactly do you mean by "suitable positivity constraints" ? If we assume  $f_k>0$ and $g_k>0$, which is what I did, wouldn't the cube be rather of the form $[-L,K]\times [-L,K]$ for some $L>0$ ?

Comment: The positivity has the vector field pointing inwards of the first quadrant on the positive half axes, so in is pointless to try for $L>0$.